# New to C/C++ Language. What has gotten wrong?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

and thank you for viewing this post. I need some help for my programming. I used to compile with turbo pascal and now I'm learning C++. Here's the problem.
I want to make a mathematics thing with an input and output something like this.
Input(in pseudocode):

```
Var a,b:=int; op:=char;
readln(a);
readln(b);
case op of
"+" : write(a+b);
"-" : write(a-b);
">" : if a>b then write("true"); else write("false");
```

I've tried to do it in C++ like this but it failed to be compiled. I don't put include here because i don't really understand why is it become bold. I wrote it something like this.

```
void main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    char op;
    std::cin>>a>>op>>b;
    switch (c){
    case (std::cin>>op == "+") :{
        c=a+b;
        std::cout<<c<<std::endl;
                           }
    }
}
```

this is the error

1>test03.cpp(10): error C2051: case expression not constant

1>test03.cpp(14): warning C4060: switch statement contains no 'case' or 'default' labels
can anyone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign any value to c, it contains garbage when you want to use it in the switch block.

I think You wanted to write

```
switch(op)
```

and

```
case '+'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not too far off the mark. The compiler is telling you exactly what the problem is. You must use a constant in your case expression.

You have a few other problems in there too and you have no error handling.

But to help you get started, try this ...

```
void main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    char op;

    std::cin >> a >> op >> b;

    switch(op){
    case '+':
        c = a + b;
        break;
    }

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```